# How to add class to particular li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<ul class="how-long">
    <li value="1">Any</li>
    <li value="1">1 day</li>
    <li value="2">Week end</li>
    <li value="7">1 Week</li>
    <li value="14">2 Week</li>
    <li value="21">3 Week</li>
</ul>
```

On document ready I want to add new class to the 4th li element.

This is  what I tried:

```
$(".how-long li").slice(3).addClass('change-color');
```

If I put an alert as:

```
alert($(".how-long li").slice(3).html());
```

it gives me  **1 week** which is right, but when I addclass the class is added to all li after 4th li.

I want to this **without adding ID** to each li element.
I can hard code class in li element directly but I want to do it dynamicaly using jQuery.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do it in one selector, use `nth-child` or `eq`:

`nth-child` is **considerably faster**, see my jsPerf here: http://jsperf.com/nth-child-vs-eq

[image: jsperf]

`nth-child`:

```
$(".how-long li:nth-child(4)").addClass('change-color');
```

`eq`:

```
$(".how-long li:eq(3)").addClass('change-color');
```

The fundamental difference is that `nth-child` will give you the 4th element of **every item** with that class (regardless of whether it is a child of the current item), whereas `eq` will give you the children on the current item.

Comment: this will select third element, not fourth as i remember

Comment: @karaxuna Only for `nth-child` though. `eq` is 0 based.

Comment: Not sure about eq, I said about nth-child :)

Comment: There is a small difference between `nth-child` and `eq`. The second gives you exactly the fourth element of all matched elements, while the first gives you *all* fourth li-children (that are somewhere inside `.how-long`).

Comment: @GeorgSchölly Thanks Georg, added that into my answer.

Comment: @mattytommo - Nice answer. I just looked at this myself and noticed that `eq` is quicker if you call `.eq()` as a function rather than a pseudo selector. Check this out: http://jsperf.com/test-case-144445

Comment: @DarrenDavies Nice find, weird that `eq` is so much slower as part of the selector itself.

Answer (score 9):

```
$(".how-long li").eq(3).addClass('change-color');
```

Answer (score 2):

slice doesn't return a jQuery object, therefore you can't use the method addClass.
The right way to do what you intend is:

by index:

```
$(".how-long li").eq(3).addClass('change-color');
```

by referencing value:

```
$(".how-long li[value=7]").addClass('change-color');
```

Comment: for this particular problem by referencing the value works, but say if he wanted to add class to the second li if he was to do `$(".how-long li[value=1]")` this would also add class to the first li so go with the index option.

Comment: `.slice()` does return a jQuery object if it's used on a jQuery object.

Comment: disagree about `slice` not returning jQuery object...http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use slice method you need to specify end attribute which you are missing

```
$(".how-long li").slice(3,4).addClass('change-color');
```

Answer (score 0):

It selects the 4th because Array index's start from 0.

You could always use $('.how-long li:nth-child(4)');

More information here: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
 $(".how-long li:nth-child(4)").addClass('change-color');

 alert($(".how-long li:nth-child(4)").html());
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it this way

```
$(".how-long li:nth-child(4)").attr({'class':'test'});
```

This will add class `test` to the 4th li

Hope this heps

Comment: bad example, if later there is an existing class on the li it will be replaced with your method. however the -1 wasn't me :)